# MySQL trigger for PrestaShop doesnt get a value but only inside the trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, prestashop

i am working on a trigger to save ps_adress.dni and ps_message.message into note of the ps_customer (for sync reasons)

```sql
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `messagetocustomer`;
CREATE TRIGGER messagetocustomer AFTER INSERT ON ps_message
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE message TEXT;
  DECLARE dni VARCHAR(16);
  DECLARE address_id INT;
  DECLARE customer_id INT;

  SET message = NEW.message;
  SET customer_id = NEW.id_customer;
  SET address_id = (SELECT id_address_delivery FROM ps_orders WHERE id_order = NEW.id_order);
  SET dni = (SELECT dni FROM ps_address WHERE id_address = 7);

INSERT INTO debug_logs (message) VALUES (CONCAT('message: ', message));
INSERT INTO debug_logs (message) VALUES (CONCAT('address_id: ', address_id));
INSERT INTO debug_logs (message) VALUES (CONCAT('id_customer: ', customer_id));
INSERT INTO debug_logs (message) VALUES (CONCAT('dni: ', dni));
  

SET @note = CONCAT(dni, ' ', NEW.message);
    UPDATE ps_customer SET note = @note WHERE id_customer = NEW.id_customer;
  
  SET @address_id = address_id;
  SET @customer_id = customer_id;
  SELECT NEW.message INTO @message;  

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

for some strange reason

```sql
SELECT dni FROM ps_address WHERE id_address = 7
```

works outside just fine but inside the trigger it always is empty (7 should be address_id but for testing right now

Comment: do you mean empty as in empty string . or null, what does the debug_logs show

Comment: goood point it does not show in debug_logs so i tought its null but in fact i only know that the debug log is empty

Comment: Avoid giving declared variables the same names a column names. Changing the declared variable to vdni fixes your issue. I'm not going to post as an answer since I think it's probably a duplicate.

Comment: just for the record renaming the variables didnt fix the issues i will abondon this solutions thank you @P.Salmon for your time and help